# Variables not updating in function c#

Tags: c#, variables

I am new to the C# Language and I am sorry if this is an easy problem to solve, I have checked the website and currently I'm experiencing an issue where a variable  changed, is not causing any change in the method, this sounds pretty vague so here is some of the code below.

```
public string PlayerToIcon(int LocA, int LocB)
{
    PlayGame play = new PlayGame();
    int[,] Board = play.Board;
    int LocData = (Board[LocA, LocB]);
    if (LocData == 0) { return " "; }
    else if (LocData == 1) { return "X"; }
    else { return "O"; }
}
```

The Board is shown below and is basically a simple array. - This is in another file

```
public class PlayGame
{
    public int[,] Board = new int[3, 3]
    {          //A B C
                {0,0,0 }, // 1
                {0,0,0 }, // 2
                {0,0,0 }  // 3
    };
}
```

I made a function to change the numbers in the array and is shown to work when using direct commands, but the numbers aren't seen to change in PlayerToIcon.
For Example if it was 0, and I changed it to 1, PlayerToIcon still reads it as 0

Thank You
Sorry if this is a simple problem

## Edit

This is what changes the variables in the array, Return State makes sure it isn't changed if 1 or 2

```
public class PlayGame
{
    public bool SelectSquare(string Location, int Player)
    {
        List<int> ConvertedLocation = ConvertLoc(Location);
        Console.WriteLine(ReturnState(Location));
        Console.WriteLine(ConvertedLocation[0].ToString() + ConvertedLocation[1].ToString());
        if (ReturnState(Location) == 0) { Board[ConvertedLocation[0], ConvertedLocation[1]] = Player; return true;}
        else { return false; }
    }
 }
```

The code is not being recognised on displayer

```
public class Interface
{
    PlayGame play = new PlayGame();
    public void GenMap()
    {
        string NewLine;
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("    | A | B | C |");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------");
        new PlayGame();
        NewLine = System.String.Format("| 1 | {0} | {1} | {2} |", (play.PlayerToIcon(play,0, 0)), (play.PlayerToIcon(play, 0, 1)), (play.PlayerToIcon(play, 0, 2)));
        Console.WriteLine((string)NewLine);
        Console.WriteLine("----------------");
        NewLine = System.String.Format("| 2 | {0} | {1} | {2} |", (play.PlayerToIcon(play, 1, 0)), (play.PlayerToIcon(play, 1, 1)), (play.PlayerToIcon(play, 1, 2)));
        Console.WriteLine((string)NewLine);
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------");
        NewLine = System.String.Format("| 3 | {0} | {1} | {2} |", (play.PlayerToIcon(play, 2, 0)), (play.PlayerToIcon(play, 2, 1)), (play.PlayerToIcon(play, 2, 2)));
        Console.WriteLine((string)NewLine);
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------");
    }
    public string PlayerToIcon(int LocA, int LocB)
    {
        int[,] Board = play.Board;
        int LocData = (Board[LocA, LocB]);
        if (LocData == 0) { return " "; }
        else if (LocData == 1) { return "X"; }
        else { return "O"; }
    }

}
```

Comment: You are creating a new `PlayGame` at the very beginning of your function `PlayerToIcon`, which means everytime you call it.

Comment: Can you please show the method that changes the values in the array?

Comment: @HimBromBeere there's no need for that. I'm quite sure he's not changing `PlayGame`'s constructor anywhere

Comment: In your function you make a new Variable of "Board" so there is a local function instance and the class based one, any changes made to Board in PlayerToIcon will disappear as its not being made to the class level Board.

Comment: Please edit your question with that code. It´s hard to read code from comments.

Comment: Added the code into Question

Comment: Where do you instantiate your `PlayGame`?

Comment: PlayGame is one class inside a file,  
Just uploaded the entire play file, tried moving PlayerToIcon into PlayGame just now, it's still not being recognised
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5klod07n6c28kwa/Play.cs?dl=0

Comment: @SebastianSouthwell I can not go to dropbox from here. Still, this does not answer my question. Where do you *instantiate* it? Where did you write `PlayGame myPlayGame = new PlayGame();` or something like this, **outside** the class itself.

Comment: I instantiated the class in another file, in another public class

Comment: @SebastianSouthwell and this is the code I want you to add in your question

Comment: I added the code from the other file on to the question @Rafalon

Comment: @SebastianSouthwell check my edit, and comment under it if you do not understand something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public string PlayerToIcon(int LocA, int LocB)
{
    PlayGame play = new PlayGame(); // creates a new PlayGame
    int[,] Board = play.Board;
    int LocData = (Board[LocA, LocB]);
    if (LocData == 0) { return " "; }
    else if (LocData == 1) { return "X"; }
    else { return "O"; }
}
```

should be changed to something like this:

```
// added as param ---------vvvvvvvvvvvvv
public string PlayerToIcon(PlayGame play, int LocA, int LocB)
{
    int[,] Board = play.Board;
    int LocData = (Board[LocA, LocB]);
    if (LocData == 0) { return " "; }
    else if (LocData == 1) { return "X"; }
    else { return "O"; }
}
```

And called that way:

```
var icon = PlayerToIcon(myPlayer, 1, 1);
```

---

You could even add it as a function in your `PlayGame` class:

```
public class PlayGame
{
    public int[,] Board = new int[3, 3]
    {          //A B C
                {0,0,0 }, // 1
                {0,0,0 }, // 2
                {0,0,0 }  // 3
    };

    public string PlayerToIcon(int LocA, int LocB)
    {
        //PlayGame play = new PlayGame();
        //int[,] Board = play.Board;
        int LocData = (Board[LocA, LocB]);
        if (LocData == 0) { return " "; }
        else if (LocData == 1) { return "X"; }
        else { return "O"; }
    }
}
```

and then call it this way:

```
var icon = myPlayer.PlayerToIcon(1, 1);
```

---

### From your edited question:

```
public class Interface
{
    PlayGame play = new PlayGame();
    public void GenMap()
    {
        string NewLine;
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("    | A | B | C |");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------");
        //new PlayGame(); (WHY??)
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            NewLine = System.String.Format("| {0} | {1} | {2} | {3} |",
                i+1, 
                /*play.*/PlayerToIcon(/*play, */i, 0), 
                /*play.*/PlayerToIcon(/*play, */i, 1), 
                /*play.*/PlayerToIcon(/*play, */i, 2));
            Console.WriteLine(NewLine);
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------");
        }
    }
    public string PlayerToIcon(int LocA, int LocB)
    {
        int[,] Board = play.Board;
        int LocData = (Board[LocA, LocB]);
        if (LocData == 0) { return " "; }
        else if (LocData == 1) { return "X"; }
        else { return "O"; }
    }
}
```

This is the output I get at the beginning:

```
    | A | B | C |
-----------------
| 1 |   |   |   |
-----------------
| 2 |   |   |   |
-----------------
| 3 |   |   |   |
-----------------
```

Comment: What happens to the first argument on PlayerToIcon, is PlayGame still an argument or can I get rid of play in (/*play.*/PlayerToIcon(play, 0, 1))

Comment: @SebastianSouthwell refresh my post. Your `play` here is the one you declared `PlayGame play = new PlayGame();` at the beginning of your class. It is therefore accessible to your function and you don't need to pass it as param

Comment: Ok thx,  The Map is not generating the same way though due to the change with the for loop, 
Before

Comment: @SebastianSouthwell why not?

Comment: This is what it was like before an after

'Before                              After
  | A | B | C |                    | A | B | C |
---------------                  ---------------
1 |   |   |   |  
---------------                  ---------------
2 |   |   |   |
---------------                  ---------------
3 |   |   |   |
--------------                   ---------------'

Then again it should be an easy problem to solve, Soz Formatting On Comment

Comment: @SebastianSouthwell I can't figure this out, but anyway I added the `for` loop mostly because I didn't want to write the same thing 3 times. You can still make the changes to your original code. It is returning `" "` because `play` is initialized with `0`s

Comment: Ok, I think you actually helped fix the main problem because PlayerToIcon is working, I think I may be able to sort out the rest now, Thx @Rafalon

Answer (score 0):

Make your PlayGame a variable before calling PlayerToIcon and pass it to him like a parameter like below:

```
public string PlayerToIcon(PlayGame myGame, int LocA, int LocB)
{
    int[,] Board = myGame.Board;
    int LocData = (Board[LocA, LocB]);
    if (LocData == 0) { return " "; }
    else if (LocData == 1) { return "X"; }
    else { return "O"; }
}
```

you must to do that:

```
new PlayGame();
```

Only if you want to reset the board to "start", not evry time you want edit it.

to clarify do something like that:

```
PlayGame myGame = new PlayGame(); 
PlayerToIcon(myGame, 1, 1);
PlayerToIcon(myGame, 1, 2);
PlayerToIcon(myGame, 0, 1);
[...]
```

without create playgame evry time :)

Answer (score -1):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string playerToIcon = new PlayGame().PlayerToIcon(new PlayGame(), 0, 1); 

    }

}
public class PlayGame
{
    public int[,] Board = new int[3, 3]
    {          //A  B C
            {0,0,0 }, // 1
            {0,0,0 }, // 2
            {0,0,0 }  // 3
    };
    public string PlayerToIcon(PlayGame play, int LocA, int LocB)
    {
        int[,] Board = play.Board;
        int LocData = (Board[LocA, LocB]);
        if (LocData == 0)
        {
            return "";
        }
        else if (LocData == 1)
        {
            return "X";
        }
        else
        {
            return "0";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you return an `int[,]` when OP wants a `string`?

Comment: Returning a string won't help here as after changing the value in the array we need the updated array.

Comment: Did you really understand the purpose of `PlayerToIcon`?